# Azure Data Factory, unable to connect to linked service

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

This seems like it should have a specific tag for data factory.

I'm following the Azure Data Factory tutorial [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-get-started/#CreateDataFactory) and on the step "Create output table" I am continually getting an error unable to connect to linked service.  The error message is "Failed to connect to Linked service. ErrorCode:-2146232060."  Where can I find some troubleshooting steps for this or at least some kind of explanation of the error code?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when the name of the linked service ("AzureSqlLinkedService" in this case) doesn't match the name of the linked service you created in an earlier step.  Do check that you have a linkedservice in the tree listing whose name matches exactly the name matches the linked service name in the output table definition ("linkedServiceName": "AzureSqlLinkedService").

Also be sure "Allow Azure Services" is turned on within your Azure SQL Server as that is a common other cause of error here.